# How to build Docker Image using Docker or docker-compose from a Private Github Repo or Github Enterprise repo?

Tags: docker, build, docker-compose, dockerfile

How can I build a Docker image from a private Github Repo? Say, from github.com? I'm part of a team working on a private project and I can't have access to it without signing in.

Does it also apply for Github Enterprise? say, github.company.com? Because the project will be open-sourced and I have the same need...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Github Personal Token that has read access to the github repo. Use the token as the username with an empty password:

`https://${TOKEN}:@github.company.com/org/repo.git#branch:dir`

You can place the URL with the token and the `Dockerfile` is assumed to be in the root dir of the repo.

Any of the examples below are saved in `docker-compose.yaml`. You can build them using the command:

```
docker-compose build
```

## master branch

Here's an example:

```
version: "3"

services:
  reference:
    build: "https://f4d***3a8:@github.company.com/org/repo.git"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "--timeout=60", "config-server:8888", "--", "java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
This works! At this point, you can define an environment variable for the token such your OPS team can provide their own token.
```

## Env token with default

- You can get the `TOKEN` from the environment or use a default

```
version: "3"

services:
  reference:
    build: "https://${TOKEN:-f4d2***3a8}:@github.company.com/org/repo.git"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "--timeout=60", "config-server:8888", "--", "java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

## Dockerfile in develop branch

- You can use the branch in the URL with the `#branch`

```
version: "3"

services:
  reference:
    build: "https://${TOKEN:-f4d***a8}:@github.company.com/org/repo.git#develop"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "--timeout=60", "config-server:8888", "--", "java","-D
```

## Dockerfile in a branch and different dir

Use the dir after the branch `#branch:dir`. The example below uses the dir `docker-ci/` in the repo `github.company.com/org/repo.git`.

```
version: "3"

services:
  reference:
    build: "https://${TOKEN:-f4d***a8}:@github.company.com/org/repo.git#develop:docker-ci"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "--timeout=60", "config-server:8888", "--", "java","-D
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your formatting.  What is `@github.company.com/org/repo.git`  Company? What company?  org? what org? What happened to the github id?  How do I docker-compose build via a private repo stored at `https://github.com/userName/private-repo-name`?  Something doesn't sound right.   Many thanks,

Comment: @zipzip :) Have you heard of Github Enterprise??? :D "company" is the name of your company if you have it :) "org" and "repo" are placeholders :) Replace them with the ones you need... LOL That's a funny comment this one of yours... And finally, if the repo is private, you need to pass a "TOKEN" as an environment variable that can clone the repo... https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: Many thx for the reply and the public posting in S.O. I was responding to the title of this question `..using Docker or Docker-Compose from a Private Repo...`  Looks like the words "from a Private Repo" are not applicable here... Unless you know the exact right format for `git clone https://${xyzTOKENvalue}:@github.com/userName/repo.git` for use in a script?  That format = bad substitution error. '^) Again, thankyou.

Comment: Got it:  `git clone https://xyzTOKENvalue@github.com/userName/repo.git`  (For anybody else who gets here.  Remove the curly brackets{}, remove the $, remove the colon:)

Comment: @zipzit You know that ${TOKEN:-DEFAULT} this is a system pattern for environment variables :) When TOKEN is not provided, the DEFAULT value is used :) Therefore, this is a NORMAL way to configure.... You NEVER want to hardcode the Token in your application :) That's a security vulnerability :)

Comment: Awesome.  Its clear now.  Thx I’m just glad there’s enough here now to resolve problems for everyone. Organization ($$) vs public individual github repos, docker-compose build vs command line git clone, and the use of environment variables. Again thx for your input here.